# Detect when the user stops pressing the button?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-gesture

I have a button and I want it to execute an action only while it is long pressed.

I am able to execute the action on the long press already. The problem is: I do not know how to stop it once the user is no longer pressing down on the button.

How do I go about implementing something like this?

I am using Jetpack Compose on an Android App.

Answer (score 8):

The [Gestures API](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures) is probably what you are after.

You can use something like:

```kotlin
var longPressActive by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
  detectTapGestures(
    onLongPress = { longPressActive = true }
    onPress = {
      tryAwaitRelease()
      longPressActive = false
    }
  )
}
```

You may also find other APIs regarding drag that match your requirements. May be worth expanding on what you are ultimately trying to accomplish.

Comment: just what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: awaitRelease() does not seem to work for longPress, which was my original goal, would you happen to know the reason?

Comment: @barryalan2633 I've updated the example with how you may be able to do what you are after. Also, there are other APIs that deal with drag and drop that may help your use case. You can use the drag and drop API without dragging a component, btw.

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Here i have note, if you using scrollable containers like LazyColumn, Pager, etc. you can try tryAwaitRelease() instead awaitRelease()

Comment: I changed the `awaitRelease()` function call in this answer to `tryAwaitRelease()`. This is because the `awaitRelease()` function will throw a `GestureCancellationException` if the press is cancelled and the `longPressActive` property will then not be set to `false` according to the current logic.

Answer (score 3):

This code is not tested yet. But I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
Button(
  onClick = { /* TODO */ },
  modifier = Modifier.pointerInteropFilter {
    when(it.action) {
      MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
        // User has pressed the button
      }
      MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
        // User is no longer pressing the button
      }
      else -> false
    }
    true
  }
) {
  Text(text = "Click Me")
}
```

Don't forget about `@ExperimentalPointerInput` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, the `Button` has an argument `interactionSource`. It can be used as follows:

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()

Button(
    onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
) {

}
```

If you need to perform some action until the button is released, you can use `isPressed` with `LaunchedEffect`:

```
if (isPressed) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        // execute some action
    }
}
```

It is launched in a coroutine scope, which will be canceled as soon as `isPressed` becomes `false`.

An other option is using it with `DisposableEffect`:

```
if (isPressed) {
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        // do some action
        onDispose {
            // cancel some action
        }
    }
}
```